# Error: cannot convert 'ship' to 'ship*' in assignment

Tags: c++, structure

So I am working on a radar. I made a version for only one ship and everything worked fine. For some reason this version does not work.

Compiler:
Error: cannot convert 'ship' to 'ship*' in assignment

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct ship{
    char name;
    int x;
    int y;
};
ship setPosition(ship space_ships[], int amount);
void update(ship space_ships[], char radar[][20], int x, int y);
```

```
int main () {
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    ship space_ships[2];
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    char radar[10][20];
    update(space_ships, radar, x, y);
    return 0;
}

ship setPosition(ship space_ships[], int amount){
        for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
            int liczba = rand()%10;
            int znak = rand()%26 + 65;
            space_ships[i].x = liczba;
            space_ships[i].y = 2*liczba;
            space_ships[i].name = znak;
            return space_ships[i];
        }
}


void update(ship space_ships[], char radar[][20], int x, int y){
    space_ships = setPosition (space_ships, 2);
    Sleep(2000);
    system("cls");
    update(space_ships, radar, x, y);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't guess which line produces the compiler error. Could you show that line?

Comment: this line: space_ships = setPosition (space_ships, 2);

Comment: Among other things, `for (...) { .... ; return value; }` looks rather wrong, since it will only perform one iteration, at most.

Answer (score 0):

space_ships = setPosition (space_ships, 2);
This happens because your function setPosition returns value type "ship". And then you are trying to assign this to array (space_ships).

Comment: Isn't it a correct way to do this? I return the type, because if I don't it will not change at all - it will operate on the copy, not on the original.

Comment: Well, you cannot assign the value of different type. Probably you need to do the following:ship* setPosition(ship* space_ships, int amount){
        for (int i=0; i<amount; i++){
            int liczba = rand()%10;
            int znak = rand()%26 + 65;
            space_ships[i].x = liczba;
            space_ships[i].y = 2*liczba;
            space_ships[i].name = znak;
        }
        return space_ships;    
}
void update(ship* space_ships, char radar[][20], int x, int y){
    setPosition (space_ships, 2);
    Sleep(2000);
    update(space_ships, radar, x, y);
}

Comment: Different type? I just made type 'ship' and created an array of that type. I might be a little confused right now.

Comment: Array is already a different type. You cannot assign type "ship" to array of "ship"(s).

Comment: Okay. Literally didn't know this. Is there a way doing it without pointers?

Comment: try to use std:: vector

Answer (score 0):

SetPosition doesn't do what you think it does. In your case it changes position of first ship in array and exits, returning that ship's object copy.